# How to set maximum number of users in Linux?

Tags: users, useradd

For example, let's say that I want a maximum of 3 users.

How can I make sure that no more than 3 users can be created?

Answer (score 3):

To set a maximum number of users that can be created, change the value of `UID_MAX` in `/etc/login.defs`

To show that this works I changed `UID_MAX` from 60000 to 1001.

Old values:

> UID_MIN       1000
> UID_MAX      60000

New values:

> UID_MIN       1000
> UID_MAX       1001

Currently I only have one user with `uid=1000`:

```
fred:~ $ id fred
id=1000(fred) gid=1000(fred) groups=1000(fred),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev)
```

I create a new user:

```
fred:~$ sudo useradd testuser
```

It is successfully created as expected, so I try to create another:

```
fred:~ $ sudo useradd testuser2
useradd: Can't get unique UID (no more available UIDs)
useradd: can't create user
```

and it fails to create additional users.

**Update:**

To answer doneal24's question. This does not work if UID is specified from the command line.

```
fred:~ $ sudo useradd testuser2
    useradd: Can't get unique UID (no more available UIDs)
    useradd: can't create user
fred:~ $ sudo useradd -u 1100 testuser2
```

testuser2 was successfully created.

Comment: Does this still work if explicit `uid` and `gid` values are supplied on the command line?

Comment: Since root can also add users through directly modifying `/etc/passwd` the safest solution is to not allow root access to anybody who might want to create a new account. They need root to add users and if they have root they can undo any blocks you might put in place.